# Иключение при обновление таблицы MySQL БД при помощи PreparedStatement

Tags: jdbc, preparedstatement

при попытке обновления таблицы

```
/**
 * Updates user
 * @param user
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public void updateUser(User user) throws SQLException {

    String updateQuery = "UPDATE users SET user_id = ?, name = ?"
                         + "WHERE user_id = ?";

    connect();

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

    preparedStatement.setInt(1,user.getId());

    preparedStatement.setString(2,user.getName());

    preparedStatement.execute();

    preparedStatement.close();

    disconnect();
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {

    UserAccesser userAccesser = new UserAccesser("root","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb" +
                                                                        "?verifyServerCertificate=false"+
                                                                        "&useSSL=false"+
                                                                        "&requireSSL=false"+
                                                                        "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false"+
                                                                        "&amp"+
                                                                        "&serverTimezone=UTC","powerlum925");

    userAccesser.connect();

    userAccesser.updateUser(new User(65,"testUser65"));



}
```

возникает исключение:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:127)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:414)
at com.cheerbuilder.dbAccess.UserAccesser.updateUser(UserAccesser.java:165)
at com.cheerbuilder.dbAccess.UserAccesser.main(UserAccesser.java:205)
```

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users SET user_id = ?, name = ?"
                     + "WHERE user_id = ?"
```

Три параметра (знаки вопроса). Сетишь только два. О чем тебе и говорит компилятор.
"No value specified for parameter 3"

Comment: Суть исключения ясна, но у меня в таблице ДВА атрибута, а не три...

Comment: Таблица здесь не причем. Ругается компилятор на ошибку в коде. У тебя в запросе три входных параметра(?), вместо каждого нужно установить значение методом setXXXX(setInt, setString.....). Ты установил только два параметра.

Comment: Спасибо большое!